# Teradata how to create a column of type inter and length 30

Tags: database, types, teradata

I am getting some syntax error while creating teradata table

create table test1(column1 integer(20));

I want to create column1 of type integer and size 20.

Also what is the default value for character and integer datatype in teradata

Answer (score 0):

There's no *display width* for an integer column in Standard SQL/Teradata. The closest thing you might get is applying a format (but it's only used when casting to a string):

```
integer format '-(19)9' -- 20 chars, leading spaces, floating sign
integer format '-9(19)' -- 20 chars, fixed length, leading zeroes
```

Btw, the precision of an INT is 10 digits, you might want a BIGINT for larger values. Or a NUMBER with up to 38 digits.

There's no default for the length of a VarChar, must be specified. For a CHAR it's CHAR(1).

Comment: What will be the default size, if we dont specify integer size. Also which is the system table which stores datataype and its value

Comment: What default size? An INT is stored in 4 bytes and always a signed value between -2147483648 and 2147483647. Similar for byteint (1 byte), smallint (2 bytes) and bigint (8 bytes). `dbc.ColumnsV` stores metadata about columns.

Comment: Suppose I dont specify the size for a integer , then  what would be the length of the datatype. Ex create table test(a character(20)) here length of the character datatype is 20

Comment: The length is based on the maximum value, i.e. leading sign plus 10 digits = 11 characters when casted to a string